# Trying to solve Geocaching puzzle

Tags: geocaching

I'm trying to solve [this Geocaching puzzle](https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC4PMD7_unthemed-2).

> NZ NO PE KR AT AT PE AT UK MM SE
>
> Hint: Puzzle includes acting

The answer to the puzzle should give some GPS coordinates, most likely in the following format: *N 54° 59.000' W 001° 35.000'*

The only thing I can find that looks even somewhat close are the [ISO Country Codes](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm), but I'm not sure how that would relate to the hint.

Comment: If you are going to make a habit of posting all your puzzles and gaining all your rep from a single source, I think you may be better off taking your requests for help to a forum specifically for geocaching.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that the source of the puzzles mattered so much.

Comment: We -prefer- original content here when possible. That isn't to say that nobody can post pre-existing puzzles, but this seems to be the equivalent of posting problems page-by-page from an uncommon book. It just doesn't feel kosher, so to speak. I've asked others to weigh in, so feel free to take my comment with a grain of salt until then.

Comment: It does matter; we [do not accept questions from ongoing contests and the like](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1675/25966), and this could be considered a breach of that policy.

Comment: For the record, your first post was discussed among the regulars and was passed off with a questionable "meh". Now that this is all you're doing here, we aren't feeling as charitable.

Comment: Well Geocaching isn't a competition it's just a game. I mean it's not like I'm posting the same kind of puzzles, this is entirely different to the last. I'm not sure I see the problem myself but it's possible I could have misunderstood the scope of this site.

Comment: Perhaps if you find yourself unable to solve these alone or with friends, you should try a more straightforward method of sourcing your caches. There are sites that will *give* you the coordinates, which seems to be what you are hoping to accomplish by coming here.

Comment: I would have thought a site dedicated to puzzles is pretty straightforward. There are other examples on here of questions like mine regarding geocaching puzzles and I can't see any complaints, not sure why my questions are so different

Comment: The puzzle has a cited source and geocaching isn't a puzzling competition. Although the puzzle is very short and vague, it seems like a fair question for this site.

Comment: You are within your right to post such questions here, which is not the point I was arguing -- but be aware that users tend to become aware of trends and also tend to reflect that with downvotes. My real complaint was that your posting habits elicit the feeling that comes with using the word "technically" ("*Technically* it's fine, but.... ehhhhhh"). More importantly, however, I would like to point out that your links to the source material lead to "Premium-only" content, and I believe your reposting it here goes against the OP's original intent.

Comment: Ahh didn't realise that was a premium cache. I do see your point about that aspect of it. It doesn't address the wider issue of it being "Technically fine, but....ehhh" As someone who is new to this site i'm not entirely sure what i'm supposed to do with that kind of feedback!? You may have a point on the trends thing, i'll take your word for that but I don't see how a variety of puzzles from one source is in any way an issue. 

That being said i understand you are probably just speaking from experience of this site more than anything.

Comment: I recommend moving this discussion to a separate chat.

Comment: I think what @feelinferrety is trying to say (do correct me if I'm wrong) is that repeatedly posting puzzles, even  completely different ones, will start to accumulate downvotes as users here will find them a) boring and repetitive and b) a method of getting quick rep. It also looks like you aren't trying to make your own puzzles and aren't putting  any effort in by copying a puzzle from another site, even if you do source it. I understand you are new and just trying to solve puzzles you can't solve, but posting puzzles from other places repeatedly won't earn you any friends here I'm afraid :/

Comment: I'd be surprised if unique puzzles would be seen as boring and repetitive. I was thinking that it would be the exact thing this site would prefer. I don't so much care about rep and not sure how posting a puzzles in this fashion would be seen and a method of getting quick rep. Looking the experience I've had so far it's clear that won't be the case.

Comment: Finally solved this one and now finding myself in the same bind of wether to share the answer or not. I won't be doing but that still feels wrong in the context of this site. I probably wont be posting GC puzzles here until I come to do my own one day.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a premium member but I do geocaching